# Log all levels only when there is a log event at warn or more severe levels

Tags: java, logging, log4j2, logback

How to log all levels' events (i.e info, debug, trace, warn, error and fatal) only when error, fatal or warn level log events are encountered otherwise log only info levels. This ensures that debug and trace logs (which are usually very large) are logged only when necessary (i.e. when there are detected warnings or errors) and hence saves space and accelerates performance.

Comment: How many log events *before* the error-level event should be buffered so they can be flushed when the error-level event occurs? --- How many, or for how long, should log events *after* the error-level event be logged?

Comment: It basically means that you want to keep an X log events in memory in a queue until an error arrives, then flush the queue. Or, if no error arrives keep chopping queue's tail to keep only X events and not more. I don't think there's a solution out of the box, you'll have to roll a custom handler or something, depending on what actual logging you're using.

Comment: @Andreas There is no limit like that. **All** events before have to be queued somehow. If at termination we haven't encountered error level yet, then the queue is cleared. If we encounter an error, all previous logs and all logs after encountering such an event will be logged.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov What is the best way to do it. Does any logging framework provide such a facility by changing configurations.

Comment: @AkshayGRao *Best way:* Create a new log file on startup. On program exit, delete the file if no errors. Prevents the need for wasting a lot of memory caching the log entries. Create a custom `Appender` to effectuate that.

Comment: @Andreas No that is hard to do Bcoz many users simultaneously write to a common log file . So even if I can isolate the levels in different files. I will be not able to delete the unwanted log of a particular thread or user. Deleting a particular level log file will delete logs of other users who might have encountered errors as well which is not acceptable ryt.

Comment: @AkshayGRao *"even if I can isolate the levels in different files"* Why would you isolate *levels* in different files? Each application instance would create a separate file, but only one log file per running application, receiving all log levels, and the application would then delete the file *on exit* (after closing the log file) if no error occurred.

Comment: @Andreas When I don't have error, I don't want to erase all the logs i need to keep info level logs.

Comment: @Andreas sorry I had forgotten to mention that I wanted info logs when no errors are encountered

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you vote for [LOG4J2-1137](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1137).